# Подкаталоги в базах данных

Tags: sql, база-данных, nosql

Здравствуйте, уважаемые, возник такой вопрос:
А какие существуют способы создания в базах данных подкаталогов?
Допустим следующую ситуацию:
У нас есть многопользовательская система, по логике - у каждого пользователя может быть несколько таблиц с данными, очень круто было бы нечто подобное

user1/

- table_one
- table_two

user2/

- table_one
- table_two

user3/

- table_one
- table_two

Как реализовать подобное средствами SQL или даже NoSQL? Сталкивались с такой проблемой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если речь об устройстве некоторого подобия multi-tenancy (много пользователей сидят как бы в изолированных средах), то отдельные СУБД (точно есть в PostgreSQL и MS SQL) позволяют создавать множество пространств имен ("schema") в рамках одной БД.

Ну и запросы будут вида:

```
select ... from user1.table_one
select ... from user2.table_one
```

Плюс на пространства имен можно раздавать права.

Comment: Можно подробней об этой технологии? Где почитать?

Comment: В доке, например: 

 - http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms190387(v=sql.105).aspx
 - http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-schemas.html

Comment: Так же точно есть в Oracle, причем в более жестком виде - там вообще пользователь базы данных автоматически получает свою собственную схему данных, которая для него является схемой по умолчанию. 
Ну и в MySQL тоже есть схемы.

Answer (score 1):

Варианты:

1. В каждой table_one, table_two добавить поле user - и вести отбор по нему.
2. При создании юзера создавать группу таблиц с префиксом, префикс хранить в профиле юзера.

Какой вариант оптимальный - тут нужна конкретика по вашему приложению

UPDATE:

Ну если совсем кардинально - то при создании Юзера создавайте отдельную БАЗУ с Таблицами, а если есть общие для все данные - их в отдельную БАЗУ

UPDATE2:

я так понимаю там система для учета данных создается. Скорее всего будет предоставляться как сервис. Т.е. создание Юзера не будет частым явлением

Comment: Такой вариант рассматривал.   
Но хотелось бы более интеллектуальное решение. ( например из области NoSQL )

Comment: хм... ) а чем именно такие варианты не нравятся? есть какие то ограничения, неудобства использования? Просто других я не встречал.

Comment: Касательно второго варианта: пользователей будет очень большое количество и тогда разобраться в таблицах станет очень и очень сложно =)  
С первым - тоже самое, слишком большое количество данных перегрузит эти таблицы.

Comment: ничего не перегрузит. Базы данных рассчитаны на то, что бы хранить много данных.

Или у Вас молодой амбициозный проект, перед которым фейсбук и гугл будут просто детскими игрушками?:)

Comment: Система создаётся для трекинга событий на различных сайтах. По этому подразумевается ОЧЕНЬ частый insert

Comment: очень частый это 10-20 штук в минуту? Проводили оценку?

Comment: Просто insert, если на таблицу не навешаны сложные индексы и тригеры - сама по себе операция быстрая, ведь по сути дела надо (грубо говоря) просто дописать данные в конец страницы и сохранить на диск

Answer (score -2):

Ты хочешь странного. Твоё желание было бы адекватным, если бы речь шла о разных классах пользователей, имеющих совершенно разные данные, которые хранятся по-разному. А если эти таблицы имеют одинаковую структуру, то городить такое -- нести зло в этот мир.

Тогда нужно использовать `user_id` в этих `table_one`, `table_two` и не выпендриваться.